# How to automate downloading of subtitles for torrents

Tags: python-3.x, automation, command-line-interface, bittorrent, subtitle

I know the title is really vague but anyways, I have a script for downloading the subtitles of a series or movie once the torrent is done downloading. The Input needs to be the filepath of the downloaded file. Conveniently uTorrent has a support for running the script once a torrent finishes downloading and has the filepath as one of its "parameters". I tried running the script with

```
C:\python\subtitles.py %D
```

where %D is the supported utorrent parameter for the filepath. This did not work as the script loaded then prompted for user input.Any help on how to automate this would be helpful.

```
from datetime import timedelta

from babelfish import Language
from subliminal import download_best_subtitles, region, save_subtitles, scan_videos

import os
# configure the cache
region.configure('dogpile.cache.dbm', arguments={'filename': 'cachefile.dbm'})

path = str(input("enter filepath:"))

# scan for videos newer than 1 week and their existing subtitles in a folder
videos = scan_videos(path, age=timedelta(days=7))

print("scan success")
# download best subtitles
subtitles = download_best_subtitles(videos, {Language('eng')})

print("downloads done")
# save them to disk, next to the video
for v in videos:
    save_subtitles(v, subtitles[v])
```

Comment: Question title could be: How to get the arguments from the "run a script after torrent finished downloading" feature of uTorrent in python

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're trying to get the "parameters" from stdin while your bittorrent client is passing the path as a command-line argument.

Replace `path = str(input("enter filepath:"))` with

```py
import sys

path = sys.argv[1]
```

and it'll work.

Comment: Thanks let me test this and get back to you